# Python: How to merge two lists into one

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
if list1:
    merged += list1
    list1 = []
elif list2:
    merged += list2
    list2 = []
```

So I append one list to another list and then make it empty.
Is there any ways to write whis part:

```
merged += list1
list1 = []
```

shorter and faster (more efficient), on one line using a function etc?

Comment: Martijn's answer is good. Though I think it's worth noting - if you are doing this, you probably have a control flow / scope in your program that could be improved - the need to manually 'reset' multiple lists seems like it mostly shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the assignments on one line:

```
if list1:
    merged, list1 = merged + list1, []
elif list2:
    merged, list2 = merged + list2, []
```

You can pick the source list in one line too:

```
source = list1 or list2 or []
merged, source[:] = merged + source, []
```

This updates `list1` or `list2` if either of them had elements through slice assignment.

Demo:

```
>>> def demo(list1, list2, merged):
...     source = list1 or list2 or []
...     merged, source[:] = merged + source, []
...     return list1, list2, merged
... 
>>> demo([], [], [1, 2])
([], [], [1, 2])
>>> demo([3, 4], [], [1, 2])
([], [], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> demo([3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2])
([], [5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> demo([], [5, 6], [1, 2])
([], [], [1, 2, 5, 6])
```

That said, I think you should stick to your original version. It is more efficient (`.extend()` or `+=` on a `list` expands the existing `list` object, the above code always builds an entirely new object, even when `list1` and `list2` are both empty), and is clear and simple, so more readable. It's great that we get to show off our Python fu from time to time, but this may not be the place, actually. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will stick to my original code then because I think it is already as easy as possible

Comment: @SomeOne: Sure, I agree actually. Slice assignment in a great tool, but using it just to merge a few lines into a one-liner is not the best place. And note that your code doesn't rebuild `merged`, just uses `.extend()`, and only if either `list1` or `list2` is not empty. Your original code is more efficient.